# Make points in a plot a certain colour

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color

Basically I have:

```
ListPlot[
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}
]
```

Basically I want the points {x1, y1}, {x2, y2} and {x3, y3} to have different colors based on an input from a Manipulate function, and I don't want to use the Hue function or make it dependent on values of the points

Comment: Is it limited to three data points? ;s

Comment: Yes, only 3 data points and each one will be a different colour

Comment: Please describe the form of the inputs are to take and what kind of control you want to use to get input from the user.

Comment: You could do `ListPlot[List /@ points, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]`, where `points = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}`.

Comment: Why not use `Graphics[]` directly?

Comment: `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{{{1, 4}}, {{3, 5}}, {{-2, 2}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {a, b, c}], {a, {Red, Green, Blue}}, {b, {Red, Green, 
   Blue}}, {c, {Red, Green, Blue}}]`